# Checkbox disapperaing when clicked

Tags: android

When I put simple checkbox run the app and click on it it completely disappears not showing the check-mark. I didn't changed the activity `.java` file where it is and here is the XML

```
<CheckBox
        android:id="@+id/checkBox"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:focusable="false"
        android:checked="false"
        android:layout_below="@+id/etConfirmPassword"
        android:layout_alignStart="@+id/etConfirmPassword" />
```

Comment: Can you post the entire xml please

Answer (score 0):

Maybe check theme? Maybe it's not visibility but colour which is the same as background.